# WPF UserControls with different inner datagrid ItemSource attribute

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got three UserControls named UC. They are all the same except that the DataGrid they use within the layout needs a different DynamicResource for each. Basically :

```
<DataGrid ...
 ItemsSource="{DynamicResource Model1}"> <!-- I want to pass in this "Model1" string? -->

...
</DataGrid>

<DataGrid ...
 ItemsSource="{DynamicResource Model2}">

...
</DataGrid>

<DataGrid ...
 ItemsSource="{DynamicResource Model3}">

...
</DataGrid>
```

All of my user controls are created within a Window :

```
<Window ...>

<my:UC/>
<my:UC/>
<my:UC/>

</Window>
```

As of right now my three UC's show the same data in the datagrid cause the dynamicresource is the same in all three, how do I pass a value to each usercontrol to change the dynamicresource within? Or how should this be handled I started doing WPF a day ago.

Thanks

Comment: Does your `UserControl` contain any other data bindings? If not, you can just pass the Model in as the `DataContext` (`<my:UC DataContext="{DynamcResource Model1} />`), and bind `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding }" />`

Comment: Thanks for this tip, I don't know if I'll have more data bindings so I rather use SnowFather's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dependency property in your user control which will hold the `ItemsSource` value ([DependencyProperty.Register](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597500.aspx)). In your control bind `DataGrid` to this property. Then set this property in your window from dynamic resources:

```
<Window ...>
    <my:UC DataGridItemsSource="{DynamicResource Model1}" />
    <my:UC DataGridItemsSource="{DynamicResource Model2}" />
    <my:UC DataGridItemsSource="{DynamicResource Model3}" />
</Window>
```

In order to bind `DataGrid.ItemsSource` in your control you can use either binding with `ElementName=parentName` or binding with `RelativeSource=FindAncestor`

Comment: I've never written a dependency property. I'm done reading on them, should it be of type string? My XAML is throwing an exception, something about my constructor being wrong because it doesn't match the binding properties.

Comment: I've figured it out. The type of the DP is obviously of IEnumerable since the property is a collection. Thanks for setting me on the right track, didn't know what keywords to search for initially.